# after maven package, the war appears repeat jars, but it not repeats before maven package

Tags: hibernate, maven

the "hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.5.Final.jar" isn't conflicts before maven package in maven ,as the picture below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pU1nG.png)

but after maven package , there are 2 "hibernate-entitymanage" jars  as the picture below. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qablm.jpg)

it leads to the failure of the project,but success after delete "hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar"

but I want to figure out the reason why maven package add another "hibernate-entity" jar.

the pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.sgcc</groupId>
<artifactId>Pkgs</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Pkgs Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
        <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
        <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
        <version>0.17.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.18</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
        <artifactId>ant</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- MarkdownJ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.markdownj</groupId>
        <artifactId>markdownj</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.0-1.0.2b4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jgit</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.jgit</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.201506240215-r</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
        <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.4</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.zywx.appdo.facade</groupId>
        <artifactId>appdo-facade-user</artifactId>
        <version>4.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.zywx.appdo.facade</groupId>
        <artifactId>appdo-facade-mam</artifactId>
        <version>4.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.zywx.appdo.facade</groupId>
        <artifactId>appdo-facade-omm</artifactId>
        <version>4.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.101tec</groupId>
        <artifactId>zkclient</artifactId>
        <version>0.4</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
                <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.6</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.zxing/core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jodd</groupId>
        <artifactId>jodd</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.8</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>Pkgs</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Can you share your `pom.xml`? Is there any parent module or multiple versions of `hibernate-entitymanager` is added as dependency?

Comment: OK, I'll add it  above

Comment: Are you using Eclipse IDE? If so check the `Dependency Hierarchy` for your `pom` file. and filter `hibernate-entitymanager`

Comment: e……bro , i did it，you can see it on the first picture above.

Comment: Ohh Okay.. Does any of the artifacts in your `org.zywx.appdo.facade` group already have that version of entity manager?

Comment: I checked it just now, the answer is----nope.[crying]

Answer (score 0):

You could run the following maven goal.

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=hibernate-entitymanager
```

It should give the dependency conflict.  You could then exclude the version that you don't want to include as shown below

```
   <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>sample.ProjectA</groupId>
      <artifactId>Project-A</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
          <groupId>sample.ProjectB</groupId>
          <artifactId>Project-B</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions> 
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Comment: I had, but it didn't show the "hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.5.Final.jar" conflicts

Comment: Ok,  please try mvn dependency:tree and see if there are multiple hibernate-entitymanager jar. Then you exclude from one which is not required

Comment: I had, "[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.2.5.Final:compile" but there isn't conflicting imformatiom about this jar.5555555555

Comment: Ok if you have mvn dependency:tree, then under which artifact you are getting hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar.  I suspect the problem to be from artifact

Comment: I get " hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar " by myself set on pom.xml, like this :<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>

Comment: Then can you please remove this dependency, since you already have hibernate-entitymanager is already available through a different artifact.